# Failed to use Julia (0.6) and Atom (1.18.0 x64)

Tags: installation, julia, atom-editor

I uninstalled Julia 0.5 and 0.52 including folders and the Atom editor.
Then I reinstalled Julia 0.6 and in a next step, Atom 1.18.0 x64.
Within Atom, the following packages were installed afterwards:

- uber-juno 0.1.2
- julia-client 0.6.0
- ink 0.7.4
- language-julia 0.11.0

From within the Atom editor console I've got after typing `Pkg.update()` no response,

Then from within julia window: `Pkg.update()` I've got the following message:

```
julia> Pkg.update()
INFO: Initializing package repository C:\Users\Carsten\.julia\v0.6

INFO: Cloning METADATA from https://github.com/JuliaLang/METADATA.jl

ERROR: GitError(Code:ERROR, Class:OS, failed to send request: Die Serververbindung konnte nicht hergestellt werden.
)

Stacktrace:
 [1] macro expansion at .\libgit2\error.jl:99 [inlined]

 [2] clone(::String, ::String, ::Base.LibGit2.CloneOptions) at .\libgit2\repository.jl:276

 [3] #clone#100(::String, ::Bool, ::Ptr{Void}, ::Nullable{Base.LibGit2.AbstractCredentials}, ::Function, ::String, ::String) at .\libgit2\libgit2.jl:562

 [4] (::Base.LibGit2.#kw##clone)(::Array{Any,1}, ::Base.LibGit2.#clone, ::String, ::String) at .\<missing>:0

 [5] (::Base.Pkg.Dir.##8#10{String,String})() at .\pkg\dir.jl:55

 [6] cd(::Base.Pkg.Dir.##8#10{String,String}, ::String) at .\file.jl:59

 [7] init(::String, ::String) at .\pkg\dir.jl:53

 [8] #cd#1(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::String, ::Vararg{Any,N} where N) at .\pkg\dir.jl:28

 [9] update() at .\pkg\pkg.jl:228
```

Comment: What does `$ make test-libgit2` show? Or, from within Julia, `Base.runtests("libgit2")`?

Comment: Problem solved: My Anti-Virus/Firewall program blocked the execution of Julia. And  I didn't even notice that

Comment: Perhaps you could write the answer showing how you discovered the cause of the problem and also the solution.

Comment: @ rickhg12hs thanks for support